# ActiveModel first argument in form cannot contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создал модельку

```
class GoodsPurchase

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :phone, :name, :email

  validates_presence_of :phone
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with =>  /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Создал контроллер

```
class Market::Desktop::Vision::GoodsPurchaseController < CatalogController

  domain_layout 'page_screen'

  def create_message
    @goods = GoodsPurchase.new message_params
    if @goods.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:goods).permit(:phone, :name, :email)
  end
end
```

Затем вьюха

```
        <%= form_for @goods, url: goods_purchase_create_message_url, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Телефон, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "int", placeholder: "+7 (   ) 123-45-67", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Имя, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "int", placeholder: "Иванов Иван", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Email, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, class: "int", placeholder: "example@example.ru", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="articul_for_order" class="js_articul_for_order">
            <div class="row">
                <%= recaptcha_tags %>
            </div>
            <button type="" class="btn btn_middle btn_blue2">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
            <%= f.submit "Заказать обратный звонок", class: 'btn btn_middle btn_blue2' %>
        <% end %>
```

в роутах прописал

```
post "goods_purchase/create_message"
```

В итоге получаю ошибку, о том что `@goods` не может быть `nil` или `[]` Понять не могу в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил путем добавления `before_action ->{ @goods = ::GoodsPurchase.new }` в главный контроллер, или же во вьюхе можно просто сделать проверку  `if @goods`